# How do you fix google chrome being slow at start it up, due to the lsass.exe service on windows 10?

Tags: google-chrome, freeze, cpu-usage, windows-services

I've been having trouble for with chrome for the past few days.

Chrome would freeze for several minutes each time I open it up. Once Chrome starts working again everything is normal, but it's frustrating when you have to wait several minutes before you can do anything with your web browser.

I managed to find one solution to this, which I have posted as an answer below, but if anyone else has had similar problems and managed to solve them, please feel free to tell us how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to chrome's startup freezing in the comments of this chrome issue report:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=374624

This was comment #27, all credit goes to the author of the comment for figuring it out:

> I am working on this issue right now.
>
> Using some clues from you all here, I've tracked it down this.
>
> Process explorer shows a security token request and termination loop
>   happening under lsass.exe, with token being
>   \:1c42f
>
> Such as: Smith_VAIO\John:1c42f
>
> Upon inspection with Process Monitor, we see the following:
>
> 11:34:57.3492434 AM   lsass.exe   908 RegQueryKey HKLM    SUCCESS Query:
>   HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0 11:34:57.3492833
>   AM    lsass.exe   908 RegOpenKey  HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-563832473-1690269938-841482641-1000    SUCCESS Desired
>   Access: Read 11:34:57.3493295
>   AM    lsass.exe   908 RegQueryValue   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-563832473-1690269938-841482641-1000\ProfileImagePath   SUCCESS Type: REG_EXPAND_SZ, Length: 28, Data: C:\Users\John 11:34:57.3493613
>   AM    lsass.exe   908 RegQueryValue   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-563832473-1690269938-841482641-1000\ProfileImagePath   SUCCESS Type: REG_EXPAND_SZ, Length: 28, Data: C:\Users\John 11:34:57.3493926
>   AM    lsass.exe   908 RegCloseKey HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-563832473-1690269938-841482641-1000    SUCCESS 
>   11:34:57.3495197
>   AM    lsass.exe   908 CreateFile  C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Protect\S-1-5-21-563832473-1690269938-841482641-513\Preferred   PATH
>   NOT FOUND Desired Access: Generic Read, Disposition: Open, Options:
>   Sequential Access, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File,
>   Attributes: HS, ShareMode: Read, AllocationSize: n/a, Impersonating:
>   Smith_VAIO\John
>
> This behavior loops.
>
> Sometimes throwing in:
>
> 11:34:57.1073869
>   AM    lsass.exe   908 CreateFile  C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Protect\CREDHIST    SUCCESS Desired
>   Access: Generic Read/Write, Disposition: OpenIf, Options: Synchronous
>   IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Random Access, Attributes: HS,
>   ShareMode: None, AllocationSize: 0, Impersonating: Smith_VAIO\John,
>   OpenResult: Opened 11:34:57.1074461
>   AM    lsass.exe   908 QueryStandardInformationFile    C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Protect\CREDHIST    SUCCESS AllocationSize:
>   24, EndOfFile: 24, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory:
>   False 11:34:57.1074769
>   AM    lsass.exe   908 CreateFileMapping   C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Protect\CREDHIST    FILE
>   LOCKED WITH WRITERS   SyncType: SyncTypeCreateSection, PageProtection: 
>   11:34:57.1075034
>   AM    lsass.exe   908 QueryStandardInformationFile    C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Protect\CREDHIST    SUCCESS AllocationSize:
>   24, EndOfFile: 24, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory:
>   False 11:34:57.1075669
>   AM    lsass.exe   908 CreateFileMapping   C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Protect\CREDHIST    SUCCESS SyncType:
>   SyncTypeOther 11:34:57.1076805
>   AM    lsass.exe   908 CloseFile   C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Protect\CREDHIST    SUCCESS
>
> So...Using that info, I went to the path
>   "C:\Users\John\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Protect\" and found one
>   folder with a random guid that was created days ago.  lsass.exe was
>   currently still in a 'stuck' state, when I deleted this guid folder,
>   and another one was immediately created with a new guid.  The next
>   step is probably unnecessary, but I deleted the newly created guid
>   folder as well, and this time it did not respawn.  lsass.exe processor
>   time was back to normal.  I attempted to close chrome, at which point
>   it closed properly.  I reopened chrome, observed lsass use some cpu
>   for about 10 seconds, then stop.  I closed chrome, and the process
>   terminated properly yet again.  I then reopened chrome to observe the
>   same behavior as previous (normal behavior).
>
> So, conclusion, the folder located at
>   "C:\Users\\appdata\roaming\microsoft\protect\" must be
>   deleted.
>
> That worked in my case.
>
> Hope you value the info!

I'm just posting it here because I had a hard time finding this solution and I hope I can make it easier for someone else in the future.

I did exactly what the author of the comment suggested, once I deleted the folder, and reran chrome, the folder was recreated, but the chrome no longer froze. The folder has a strange name that consists of a long line of different characters, and it appears to be empty, but deleting it definitely did the trick for me.

Good luck!